# TCL scan sorting from text file

Tags: arrays, tcl, text-files

I would like to scan the following values from txt file that consist of 300 loop of asicgetmse using tcl.

Here is my plan.

1st set the empty array cell

```
asicmse{0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
```

then, set the body

```
*mse {set s s_getmse}
```

lastly do the scanning,

here is the example 
of scanning procedure.

```
s_readhs
{
   set y [scan $x {%[^:]: %i %i %i %i}]
   switch -nocase [string trim [lindex $y 0]] pga {
       set a(hsbus) [lreplace $a(hsbus) 0 3 {*}[lrange $y 1 4]]
   } mse {
       set a(hsbus) [lreplace $a(hsbus) 4 7 {*}[lrange $y 1 4]]
   } rms {
       set a(hsbus) [lreplace $a(hsbus) 8 11 {*}[lrange $y 1 4]]
   } lo {
       set a(hsbus) [lreplace $a(hsbus) 12 12 {*}[lindex $y 1]]
   }
   if [string first { -- '} $x]>-1 {set s s_body}
}
```

this procedure is scanning the values for this parameters

```
Enabling High Speed Bus
PGA:  0x173  0x161  0x15a  0x165 
MSE:  0x024  0x018  0x02a  0x028 
RMS: 0x2107 0x1f97 0x2003 0x1fbc 
LO : 0x01fd6 (167.178MHz) 
PASS -- 'readhsbus'
```

Can some one help me to modify the procedure the scan the values for asicgetmse?

```
HI MSE 0x017 (1.1%, -19.50dB)
HQ MSE 0x01a (1.3%, -18.96dB)
VI MSE 0x031 (2.4%, -16.21dB)
VQ MSE 0x027 (1.9%, -17.20dB)
PASS -- 'asicgetmse'
```

the expected value in `.plt` file

```
HI% HIdB  HQ%  HQdB    VI% VIdB   VQ%  VQdB
1.1 -19.5 1.3  -18.96  2.4 -16.21 1.9  -17.20 



     s_getmse
     {
        set y [scan $x {%[^:]: %i %i %i %i}]
        switch -nocase [string trim [lindex $y 0]] Percentage {
            set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 0 3 {*}[lrange $y 1 4]]
        } dB {
            set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 4 7 {*}[lrange $y 1 4]]
        } 

        if [string first { -- '} $x]>-1 {set s s_body}
     }
```

I'm not familiar with index and array. can some one help me please?

```
 s_getmse
 {
    set y [scan $x {%*s %*s %*s (%f%*s, %f%*s)}]
    switch -nocase [string trim [lindex $y 0]] himse {
        set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 3 4 {*}[lrange $y 1 2]]
    } hqmse {
        set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 8 9 {*}[lrange $y 1 2]]
    } vimse {
        set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 13 14 {*}[lrange $y 1 2]]
    } vqmse {
        set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 18 19 {*}[lrange $y 1 2]]
    } 
    if [string first { -- '} $x]>-1 {set s s_body}
 }
}
```

hope this might working.

now I'm able to copy the value.

```
  {HI MSE*} { set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 0 0 [lindex $x 3]] }
  {HQ MSE*} { set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 1 1 [lindex $x 3]] }
  {VI MSE*} { set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 2 2 [lindex $x 3]] }
  {VQ MSE*} { set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 3 3 [lindex $x 3]] }
```

It's copying the the whole index 3 `(1.1%,`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you need help, your question need to be specific. You need to show the input, the desired output, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: this application is to plot the graph using gnuplot and tcl to create the array table. tcl wil scan all the parameters from the log file. i have tried this function to scan the % values. HI* {set a(hi_per) [lindex $$x "%*s %*s (%f%*s"1]}. but not working.

Comment: Would you please update your post with what you have tried? It is hard to see in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
set line "HI MSE 0x01b (1.3%, -18.80dB)"
scan $line "%s %s %x (%f%%, %fdB)" hi mse hex_number percent db
```

I believe you missed the `%x` to scan the hex number.
**Correction**: I meant `%x` (was: `%s`).

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote in an edit:

> OK. Done finally got it.
>
> ```
>  s_getmse
>  {
>     set y [lindex $x 3]
>     set v [string trim $y "(%,"]
>     switch -nocase [lindex $x 0] {
>     HI {set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 0 0 $v]}
>     HQ {set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 1 1 $v]}
>     VI {set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 2 2 $v]}
>     VQ {set a(asicmse) [lreplace $a(asicmse) 3 3 $v]}
>     default {if [string first " -- " $x]>0 {set s s_body}}}
>
>     set z [lindex $x 4]
>     set w [string trim $z "dB)"]
>     switch -nocase [lindex $x 0] {
>     HI {set a(asicdb) [lreplace $a(asicdb) 0 0 $w]}
>     HQ {set a(asicdb) [lreplace $a(asicdb) 1 1 $w]}
>     VI {set a(asicdb) [lreplace $a(asicdb) 2 2 $w]}
>     VQ {set a(asicdb) [lreplace $a(asicdb) 3 3 $w]}
>     default {if [string first " -- " $x]>0 {set s s_body}}}
>  }
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in an edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))